# Unable to parse onClick text using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

All that I have read says to use the *element*.onclick property, but that doesn't seem to be working in my situation. I'm trying to parse the number: 629216818 and set it to a varialbe: fbid. This is a Greasemonkey script, so the HTML can't be edited directly. I'm no pro, so I may be just doing something stupid, but here is my HTML and Javascript:

```
<div id="petRightContainer">
<a title = "Pet trainer bonus: Your companion will level 5% faster." href="setup.php?type=companion&gtRandom=8167343321487308">
<div class="petRight" style="background-image:url(/fb/res/gui4/companion/cu_sith.jpg)"></div>
</a>
<div class="petRightLevel">
<a href="#" onClick="publishToWall('http://www.ghost-trappers.com/fb', 'Look at the cool augmentations my companion has received on Ghost Trappers.', 'Look at my new companion on Ghost Trappers!  I\'ve named it Jankie.  ', null, 'index.php?si=629216818&fromWall=1', 'white/companion_32.jpg', 'companion/wallpost_augmentation_12.jpg', 'companion/wallpost_augmentation_21.jpg', 'companion/wallpost_augmentation_11.jpg', null)">Dog</a>                        
</div>
```

etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    fbid = 0;
    fbidRegex = /\d{3,}(?=&fromWall=1)/;

    if ( document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0]){

       element = document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0].firstChild;
       codeStore = element.onclick;
       fbid = fbidRegex.exec(codeStore);
       document.write("it is working ");
    }

    document.write(fbid);

</script>
```

Comment: And where is the correspondent HTML element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0].firstChild;
```

If you are using Firefox and other browsers which support `document.getElementsByClassName` and in your HTML, there are spaces between `<div class="petRightLevel">` and

```
<a href="#" onClick= ...>
```

, the firstChild is actually a text node not the link. All you need to do is remove the spaces and/or line break in between the two elements.

If you are using IE, the problem is still at the same line of the javascript because IE doesn't support document.getElementsByClassName up until version 8.

**Update:** The following javascript code work for all the browsers I tested without touching HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    fbid = 0;
    fbidRegex = /\d{3,}(?=&fromWall=1)/;

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var link = null;

    for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
    {
       if(divs[i].getAttribute("class") ==="petRightLevel")
       {
          link = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
          break;
       }
    }
    if (link){
       codeStore = link.onclick;
       fbid = fbidRegex.exec(codeStore);
       document.write("it is working ");
    }

    document.write(fbid);

</script>
```

If you only need to get the anchors, it would be much simpler than this.

Comment: I didn't mention this initially, but the HTML is what it is because I'm working on a Greasemonkey script. I need to extract the fbid with the HTML as-is using Javascript.

Comment: @RyanHoffman: in that case, you can use document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0] to locate the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    fbid = 0;
    fbidRegex = /\d{3,}(?=&fromWall=1)/;
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0]){
        element = document.getElementsByClassName("petRightLevel")[0].firstChild;
        // callback function to execute when the element onclick event occurs.
        codeStore = element.onclick = function(){
            fbid = fbidRegex.exec(codeStore);
            document.write("it is working ");
            document.write(fbid);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want it to parse when the event occurs, I want it to parse when the page loads (Greasemonkey).